# Selection of Frequency in Switching Regulator

Tags: switching-regulator, low-noise-amplifier

The AD [ADP5070](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP5070.pdf) for feeding a low noise amplifier and a 24 bit ADC, can be regulated at two pin selectable frequencies: 1.2MHz or 2.4MHz, accepting an external oscillator in the range 1 MHz to 2.6MHz.

This regulator should work from +15V into +-16V 50mA.

In order to probably reduce the noise, which one of these selection should I pick?

Or is this selection not particularly relevant?

[image]

Comment: It's a tradeoff between efficiency, component size and transient response. You can pick whichever as long as you filter properly. You are going to need filtering anyways at 24-bits. Maybe even linear regulators for the final stage. And definitely good PCB layout. All that matters a lot more.

Comment: One consideration is beating between different oscillators. If the ADC runs at 1.25 MHz and the switcher at 1.2 MHz you can expect difficulties around 50kHz. In that case, locking the SMPS to the ADC clock may help.

Comment: nodes on that IC will be switching 15 volts in 15 nanoseconds; how close do you want that displacement-current-generating piece-of-metal to be to your 24-bit ADC and input wiring and VREF pins and ADC_GND_pins. The displacement current of 1pF and 1volt/nanosecond is 0.001amp. That current, 1mA, thru 1nH, is V = L * dI/dT = 1nH * 1mA/7.5nanoseconds = 140 microVolts. How are you planning to shield?

Answer (score 2):

There are several aspects to consider:

- If you increase the frequency, the time between two cycles goes down, so does the energy per cycle. This means you can use smaller capacitors and inductors when you target the same ripple (and really low ripple is important to make use of 24 bit ADC resolution).
- If you increase the frequency, you increase capacitive coupling (because the impedance of the parasitic capacitance between traces on the PCB decreases with frequency). So possibly you need better shielding or guard traces to avoid interference.
- You need to avoid beat frequencies between the sample rate and the converter, so every sample gets the same disturbance (hopefully this results in merely a DC offset). One way to eliminate beating is to make the converter run at an integer multiple of the sample frequency (this means: you would not use the free-running oscillator at 1.2 or 2.4 MHz, but generate your own frequency by multiplying the sample clock).